# CSS inexplicable indent

Tags: css, indentation

There is an indent in this file that is causing the element 'scroller' to have a left margin of exactly 30px; . I cannot find what is causing this. It is driving me up the wall.

The problem is somewhere is this file:
http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-css/admin/master.css

The html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller" align="left" style="left:0; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;">
        <ul id="thelist">
            <li>Pretty row 1</li>
            <li>Pretty row 2</li>
            <li>Pretty row 3</li>
            <li>Pretty row 4</li>
            <li>Pretty row 5</li>
            <li>Pretty row 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additional CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    background:#555;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}

#scroller {
    position:relative;
    /*  -webkit-touch-callout:none;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    padding:0;
    overflow:auto;
    list-style:none;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#scroller ul {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:auto;
}

#scroller li {
    padding:0 10px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    font-size:14px;
    list-style:none;

}
```

Can anyone alleviate me of my suffering and find the offending CSS?

Comment: Can't you see what's setting it using Firebug?

Comment: Should it look like that? Because I don't see any left-margin : http://jsfiddle.net/GCdvW/

Comment: Ok there you go : http://jsfiddle.net/GCdvW/1/

Comment: I think it's to do with the `li {margin-left:30px; }` found in text.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In text.css here : http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-css/admin/text.css

You have a margin-left applied to all of your list item:

```
li {
   margin-left: 30px;
}
```

You must override it when you don't want it or remove it if you don't need it anywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gpu3b/

Search for the `/* Fixed` in the css box.

Comment: I still can't see this indentation... how did you get it to "work" on jsfiddle?

Comment: I copied all of the styles provided in link above into the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GCdvW/

Comment: @Robin Knight - If this is the answer, don't forget to give him the [green check](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-accepted1.png)!

Answer (score 0):

The fix to 99% of these problems: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/CSS

You can use `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` as a quick fix, but a CSS reset sheet should be used for production.

Answer (score 0):

Test a simple CSS Reset:

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins and apdding off everything.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```